# HDD/OS install issues

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, installation

My laptop's HDD recently died. I replaced it with a new SATA HDD.

My CD drive doesn't work, so my only choice is to install things from USB.

I tried installing WinXP, but apparently it doesn't have native SATA drivers (?) I get a BSOD everytime I boot. I downgraded from Vista to XP as soon as I got the laptop, with no problems. but I'm not even sure how to find the right ones. My last HDD was SATA as well, so it can't be some kind of hardware incompatibility... can it?

I wanted to DBAN my HDD and just install archlinux, but DBAN is hanging on "PCI (sysfs)." Others have said to disable media card readers (it's the cause of the hang), but my BIOS doesn't have an option for that!

My laptop is an HP dv6700, Turion X2 TL-60.

Comment: Your BIOS should have a switch for enabling IDE mode. It's slower, but barely noticeable in real terms.

Comment: @RandolphWest Aagh, I forgot to mention, MY BIOS DOESN'T HAVE ANY CONFIGURATION OPTIONS. Except for boot order..

Answer (score 0):

There's a [nice tutorial on SevenForums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/72185-sata-drivers-slipstream-into-windows-xp-cd.html) for slipstreaming SATA drivers.
Depending upon what XP CD you have, you might also want to slipstream the latest service pack.

Comment: Having a link is nice, but would it be possible to include the most essential parts of the article here, on site? That'd be great!

Comment: Huh, interesting. I didn't get that error... (no hdd found). I just get a BSOD after installing, during the first bootup...